# Error message about Biostrings

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using a code where at some point i have something like that

```
anna <- DNAStringSet()
for (chr in c(paste('chr',seq(1,22),sep=''),'chrX','chrY')){
.
.
.
anna.view<-DNAStringSet(Views(unmasked(Hsapiens[[chr]])
.
anna<-append(anna,anna.view)
}
gc()
}
anna

library(rGADEM)
gadem <- GADEM(anna, genome = Hsapiens)

Warning message:
Using XStringViews() on a character vector is deprecated.
Please use instead something like:
  as(DNAStringSet(x)), "Views")
if you really want views, otherwise just:
  DNAStringSet(x)
```

What does that message mean? Do i have to change anything in my code, or it is safe to continue?

Comment: It would be helpful to know where the warning is coming from, e.g., set `options(warn=2)` before the warning occurs, then `traceback()` after, and finally `options(warn=0)` to reset default warning behavior. Also asking on the [bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) mailing list will get accurate answers from the people responsible for the software; be sure to cc the `packageDescription('rGADEM')$Maintainer` if that is where the warning is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning about `XStringViews` being [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) warns you that you can use this function, although it is discouraged because better alternative exist (the alternatives are suggested in the warning). However, you can still use the function.

I think the code that generates the warning comes from a function within a package. But without a reproducible example, this is hard to say. If the warning is generated from a package, upgrade to the newest version to see if that fixes the problem (although the package does not look like it is actively maintained). Alternatively, you mail the package maintainer and tell about this issue.

Bottom line, you can still use the package in your research, the warning relates to a purely software technical issue. There is no garantuee however that the code will run in new versions of R or Bioconductor, as deprecated code has a tendency to be deleted at some time.